# trying to know vowels and constants with python

Tags: python

```
Vowles = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
letter = input("what is the letter\n")
if letter = Vowles:
    print("This letter is a vowel")
elif letter = 'y':
    print("Y is sometimes a vowel and sometimes constant")
else:
    print("This letter is not a vowel")
```

what is the problem with this code
Is there is another method with using if,elif,else

Comment: `=` is used for assignment; `==` is used to test equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `=` is an assignment operator. To check if 2 values are equal use `==`.
2. To check if the `list` contains some value, use `if letter in Vowels`.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, when you check to see if 2 things match in a conditional statement such as an if statement, you use `==` instead of `=`.

Secondly, Vowles is a list. This means that the only way for the the letter to be `==` to the vowel is if the letter is exactly the same as a vowel: `["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]`.

The way to fix it is to change it from `if letter = Vowels` to `if letter in Vowels`.

This is how I did it:

```python
Vowles = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
letter = input("what is the letter/word\n").lower()
lst = list(letter)

for letter in lst:
    if letter in Vowles:
        print(f"The letter {letter} is a vowel")
    elif letter == 'y':
        print("Y is sometimes a vowel and sometimes constant")
    else:
        print(f"The letter {letter} is not a vowel")
```

Let me explain:

Line 1 creates a list which holds all the vowels.

Line 2 asks the user to enter a letter/word and calls this letter and turns it into lowercase using `.lower()`

Line 3 turns the user input into a list, so "hello" would turn into ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]

Line 4 initiates a for loop that iterates through every letter in the list.

Line 5 checks to see if the letter is in the list. If it it, then in line 6, you print that there is a vowels.

Line 7 checks to see if the letter is "y". If it is, then line 8 prints that to the user.

If it is none of these, then line 10 prints to the user that it is none of these.

Comment: This won't work.  Just try the letter - `beef` and see what's happening.

Comment: It seems that you've just copy-and-modify my Post?  I don't mind that - as long as you give the credit to the original  post?  This is not right!

Comment: Ask S/O to vertify then. I can see that you copied from me because of the fact that your post was posted 3 MINUTES after MINE! Therefore, you copied me. If honesty is the best policy, then why aren't you following it?

Comment: Someone here. See some python. And that guy.

Comment: yeah me. I'm here!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
Vowles = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
letter = input("what is the letter\n")
if letter in Vowles:
    print("This letter is a vowel")
elif letter =='y':
    print("Y is sometimes a vowel and sometimes constant")
else:
    print("This letter is not a vowel")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'in' operator to check if the letters appear in the sequence. Also use == and not = if something is supposed to equal something.

```
Vowles = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
letter = input("what is the letter\n")
if letter in  Vowles:
    print("This letter is a vowel")
elif letter == 'y':
    print("Y is sometimes a vowel and sometimes constant")
else:
    print("This letter is not a vowel")
```

Answer (score 0):

There were few errors in your code like `==` is used to compare in python instead of `=. =` is used to assign value to a variable.
Another mistake was that you can't compare the whole list with an element, that's why I used for loop to access the element of the list.

```
Vowles = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
letter = input("what is the letter\n")
for i in Vowles:
    if letter == i:
        print("This letter is a vowel")
        break
    elif letter == 'y':
        print("Y is sometimes a vowel and sometimes constant")
        break
    else:
        print("This letter is not a vowel")
        break
```